# how to capture Screen on windows that is running on macbook

Tags: macos

I want to take screen shoot from windows that is installed on macbook there is no PrintScreen button on macbook as it is on laptops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is better on the Super Users stack. But to answer your question, try using the on-screen keyboard and pressing the prnt scrn button on that.

On screen keyboard can be found in the accessibility options from control panel.